# Iterate Java Map but after skipping 1-st element

Tags: java

I have this Java Map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("//div[@col-id='actualSourceLPName']", "LP4");
map.put("//div[@col-id='actualSourceLPName']", "LP4s");
```

I want to skip the first one:

```
for (String key : map.entrySet().stream().skip(1)) {
    compareValues(driver, key, map.get(key));
}
```

But I get error: `foreach not applicable to type 'java.util.stream.Stream<java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>>'`

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: 1st element doesn't make sense anyway: `HashMap` are not ordered.

Comment: The `foreach` syntax works only on `Iterable` or `Array` types, whereas you're trying to do it on a `Stream`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Comment: + you have twice the same key, the map would contain only one entry

Comment: ok, what other collection I can use with key and value to get the required result?

Comment: If you want to store multiple String value for one key, then rather than taking a String, you can keep a list or array of String which can store several strings for a key.
For example Map<String, List<String>>

Comment: Thanks, how I can after that substring the Map?

Comment: You really need to first focus on how this map only has one entry.  The second put _overwrites_ the first, as if the first never happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First use a LinkedHashMap if you want it ordered:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("//div[@col-id='actualSourceLPName']", "LP4");
map.put("//div[@col-id='actualSourceLPName']", "LP4s");
```

You are trying to iterate a stream which doesn't work that way. Try this:

```
map.entrySet().stream().skip(1).forEach(e -> {
    compareValues(driver, e.getKey(), e.getValue());
});
```

Alternatively you can convert your stream to a list. Now your driver variable doesn't have to be "effectively final".

```
for (String key : map.entrySet().stream().skip(1).map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList())) {
    compareValues(driver, key, map.get(key));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how I can do which with while loop because I need to pass the key into the body?

Comment: The parameter e is the current map entry in the iteration. Just use getKey() or getValue() to retrieve what you need. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A `Stream` is not an `Iterable`. It does have a `forEach()` method though:

```
map.entrySet().stream().skip(1).forEach((e) -> compareValues(driver, e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

Comment: Note that you can call getValue() on each entry instead of calling map.get(e.getValue()).

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use an ordered Map instead of a HashMap, see TreeMap or LinkedHashMap
2. ***WHY*** are you skipping the first one?  A better solution would be to write a filter for the stream.  Just blanket skipping an item could cause issues later.